# abstract matrix class in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-class

I would like to create a wrapper class for a matrix library that supports, for instance, matrix multiplication:

```
MyMatrix MyMatrix::operator* (const MyMatrix & other) const { ... }
```

My first idea was that it would be cool if I create an abstact class `MyMatrix` that contains the above signature as a pure virtual function (and derive my wrappers from this), but as it turned out this is not possible because the function has an abstract return type. I'm wondering what a clean solution for this problem would look like. Or is the abstract class approach the wrong one and should I just use concrete wrapper classes?

Comment: you can return a pointer, or better a smart pointer

Comment: Ah yes, C++. The language without proper polymorphism support :)

Comment: If you just want to wrap a matrix type and provide it with proper value semantics, you can take a look at the _proposed_ Boost.QVM http://www.revergestudios.com/boost-qvm/

Comment: @Andrew: yes but I'm trying to avoid non-automatic objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
   //all the methods here

private:
    Implementation *_impl;
};
```

So the user of the class will use just `Matrix` class anywhere and you will use 'Implementaion' to implement the interface easily.

Also if you need to change the implementation later - it will not affect your client's code. Just the implementation of `Matrix` class

**Note**, that `_impl` can easy be everything, not just a pointer.

Comment: And what advantage does this give in regards to the OP's question?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: you don't have to return pointers. For the user of the class there will a transparent class Matrix. Implementation is for internal use only

Comment: I think he suggests to use Bridge pattern here. Which is a good way to transparently handle memory handling, etc.

Comment: that's exactly my current implementation but the problem here is that in case we want to switch to another implementation we would have to  _modify_ our code (by replacing the class definition) and can not just _extend_ it (by adding another derived class).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pimpl Idiom.

In your case, `Matrix`is a concrete class, that owns (holds a pointer to) an abstract `MatrixImpl`type object, and forwards all methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
virtual MyMatrix* MyMatrix::operator* (const MyMatrix & other) const = 0;
```

Comment: But then one would have to do `c = *( a * b )` to operate... and who will `delete` the temporary?

Comment: Returning pointers is a bad idea. This would be dependent upon the caller to delete the pointer later...

Comment: But if you want to return a new object then this is the way to go in C++. You cannot return a value object because the subclasses would be trimmmed down in that case, if it worked. You can either use smart pointers, or better yet you can use Bridge (Handle/Body) design pattern to simplify the API

Comment: Yes I already thought about that pointer solution but I don't like it that much because from a user's perspective it's weird that mat1 * mat2 is a pointer to the product, and one has always to delete it later.

Comment: Then, using Handle/Body (or Bridge) pattern would do the job, as I mentioned, and also presented in the other answer.